# How to plot a Pearson correlation given a time series?

Tags: data-visualization, time-series, gsl, pearson

I am using the code in this website http://blog.chrislowis.co.uk/2008/11/24/ruby-gsl-pearson.html to implement a Pearson Correlation given two time series data like so:

```
  require 'gsl'

  pearson_correlation = GSL::Stats::correlation(
    GSL::Vector.alloc(first_metrics),GSL::Vector.alloc(second_metrics)
  )
```

This returns a number such as -0.2352461593569471.

I'm currently using the highcharts library and am feeding it two sets of timeseries data. Given that I have a finite time series for both sets, can I do something with this number (-0.2352461593569471) to create a third time series showing the slope of this curve? If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: What's your data look like? What are you trying to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, correlation doesn't tell you anything about the slope of the line of best fit. It just tells you approximately how much of the variability in one variable (or one time series, in this case) can be explained by the other. There is a reasonably good description here: http://www.graphpad.com/support/faqid/1141/.

How you deal with the data in your specific case is highly dependent on what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to show that variable X causes variable Y? If so, you could start by dropping the time-series-ness, and just treat the data as paired values, and use linear regression. If you're trying to find a model of how X and Y vary together over time, you could look at [multivariate linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_linear_regression) (I'm not very familiar with this, though).